# How to install lz4 shared libraries in rpm based machines?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, lz4

I tried to install lz4 libraries in CentOS, but failing with the following error.

```
[Bash]# yum install liblz4 liblz4-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net 
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net 
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net 
No package liblz4 available. 
No package liblz4-devel available. 
Error: Nothing to do 
[Bash]#
```

What is the right way to setup the liblz4.so?

Also, I am not able to find the lz4 rpm packages for CentOS, but available for other rpm based Operating Systems. Is lz4 supported for CentOS?

Answer (score 10):

On CentOS 6.x or 7.x, you can do the following to easily install lz4 using the package manager.

As root (`sudo su -` is your friend, or just preface each yum invocation below with `sudo`):

First, enable EPEL, as @Etan Reisner suggested:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Then, to install lz4 binary:

```
yum install lz4
```

And/or, to install the library:

```
yum install lz4-devel
```

And, you're done.

Comment: May be needed: `yum install lz4 --enable-repo=epel`

Answer (score 3):

Packages for CentOS for `lz4` appear to be available in [`EPEL`](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: I could find the required rpm and able to install it through above info. But how to make yum install it automatically. This is required for a naive user.

Comment: You add the `EPEL` repo to your system and `yum` will work just fine. Information about doing that is on the page I linked.